# Cross browser issue with DIV scroller

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

To scroll down my chat DIV I am using the following code which is working awesome with Chrome & FF. And estimated to work fine with all rest popular browsers except IE. Can anybody modify the below code or provide me with some other code that does the same work (But should have cross-browser support).

```
    <style type="text/css">
            #div2
            {
                width:250px;
                height:300px;
                background-color:Aqua;
                padding:10px;
                font-family:Calibri;
                overflow:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.setInterval(function () {
                abc1();
            }, 10);

            function abc1() {
                var tb1 = document.getElementById('TextBox2');
                var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
                var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
                if (tb1.value != div1.clientHeight) {
                    div2.scrollTop = div2.scrollHeight;
                    tb1.value = div1.clientHeight;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <div id="div2">

                <div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
        </div>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Server side code:**

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    String abc1 = dr[1].ToString();
    String abc2 = dr[2].ToString();
    div1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(abc1 + ":" + abc2 + "<br />"));
}
```

Please feel free to use any technology either JavaScript/CSS/Ajax/jQuery/other but how can a scroll bar can behave in the similar manner in all browsers?

Edit 1:

Main issue is IE is not even displaying `div1.clientHeight` in `TextBox2` :( Any other way to find height for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use jQuery and use its cross browser equivalent for getting the height. i.e. `$('#div1').outerHeight()` - this will work in IE as well as all other browsers.

---

**UPDATE - Your code using jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function () {
        abc1();
    }, 10);
    function abc1() {
        var tb1 = $('#TextBox2');
        var div1 = $('#div1');
        var div2 = $('#div2');
        if (tb1.val() != div1.outerHeight()) {
            div2.scrollTop(div2[0].scrollHeight);
            tb1.val(div1.outerHeight());
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry to say. I am not much familiar with jQuery. Can you please provide me more information?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library, you can download it from jquery.com, save it in a .js file and link it to your header or link straight from jquery. It's actually a very popular library that most of the websites use in some way.

Comment: check my updated answer. I've given an example implementation using jquery.